# I tried to make a daylight cycle in my game, but once it turns to night it will not go back to day

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, pygame, raycasting

for yet another bug in my game, the daylight cycle will not work I tried to flip where:
  Time = 0
goes, but no luck, I looked into the issue and I only found ways to make day/night for other languages, and python does not like it when I try to automatically change it to day through other means.

As I described I tried to flip where:

```
Time = 0
```

goes in:

```
elif Time >= 4800:
    Time = 0
    Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth',0,0,800,600)
    ReDisplayItem()
```

but no luck, I even tried using while statements but python does not like that.

```
import pygame

#2000,1001

pygame.init()

Screen = "None"

Sobj = "None"

Width = 800

Height = 600

Time = 0

Frame = pygame.display.set_mode((Width,Height))

pygame.display.set_caption("HypoPixel")

FPS = pygame.time.Clock()

def ReDisplayItem():
    if Sobj == "None":
    Raycast('Textures/Extra/ItemBox.png',0,0,160,160)
elif Sobj == "Loom":
    Raycast('Textures/Extra/IBO.png',0,0,160,160)
    Raycast('Textures/Blocks/loom_side.png',10,10,140,140)

def Raycast(TTR, RayXPos, RayYPos, RaySizeX, RaySizeY):
    RaycastThis = pygame.image.load(TTR)
    RaycastThis = pygame.transform.scale(RaycastThis,(RaySizeX,RaySizeY))
    Frame.blit(RaycastThis, (RayXPos, RayYPos))
Loop = True
Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth.png',0,0,800,600)
Raycast('Textures/Extra/ItemBox.png',0,0,160,160)
while Loop == True:
    Time = Time + 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_0:
                Raycast('Textures/Extra/ItemBox.png',0,0,160,160)
                Sobj = "None"
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_1:
                Raycast('Textures/Blocks/loom_side.png',10,10,140,140)
                Sobj = "Loom"
    if Time >= 2400:
        Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/EarthNight.png',0,0,800,600)
        ReDisplayItem()
    elif Time >= 4800:
        Time = 0
        Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth',0,0,800,600)
        ReDisplayItem()
    pygame.display.update()

FPS.tick(60)
```

I expected night to turn to day, but it just stood dark at night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the condition `Time >= 4800` is fulfilled, then `Time >= 2400` is fulfilled, too.

The statement list in the `elif` statement is never executed, because the `if` condition is evaluated before and "wins".

So the `if` condition has to be `Time >= 2400 and Time < 4800`:

```py
if Time >= 2400 and Time < 4800:
    Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/EarthNight.png',0,0,800,600)
    ReDisplayItem()
elif Time >= 4800:
    Time = 0
    Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth',0,0,800,600)
    ReDisplayItem()
```

or the order of the cases has to be reversed:

```py
if Time >= 4800:
    Time = 0
    Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/Earth',0,0,800,600)
    ReDisplayItem()
elif Time >= 2400:
    Raycast('Textures/Screens/Skybox/EarthNight.png',0,0,800,600)
    ReDisplayItem()
```

Comment: Thanks this really helped me, ANOTHER BUG SQUASHED!